# delete windows.old remotely with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, explorer

at the moment in our company we are upgrading our windows 10 to the newest built. after the upgrade we have the windows.old folder directly under c: sometimes this folder is extremly big. how can i delete this folder remotely with powershell.
if i try to delete this folder with the explorer with \pc-name\c$ i don't have the permissions. now i want to get the acl for the folder and all subfolders with powershell but i only get the acl for the top folder. how can i get it working for the complete directory. is there any other way to delete windows.old remotly?

```
$computername = read-host "enter pc"


$script = {
# set ErrorAction to 'Stop' in order to catch errors
$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
# you're now running this on the remote pc, so use local path
$path = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\windows.old\" -recurse
try {
    $acl = Get-Acl -path $path.FullName
    $accessrule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new('username', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
    $acl | Set-Acl -path $path.FullName
    # output the message
    "{0}`t{1} success" -f (Get-Date).ToString(), $env:COMPUTERNAME 
}
catch {
    "{0}`t{1} failed" -f (Get-Date).ToString(),  $env:COMPUTERNAME
}
# restore previous ErrorAction
$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
}


$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock $script
if ($result -ne $null)
{
write-host "sucess" -ForegroundColor "green"
}
else
{
write-host "no success" -ForegroundColor "red"
}
```

Comment: Try a [group policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc730913(v=ws.11)) instead.

Comment: unfortunately not possible. needs to be a script or tool instead

Comment: take a look at cleanmgr.exe, as far as I know it can be automated